# Model Advisor Empty

Tags: matlab, simulink

sometimes when I go to *Analysis* -> *Model Advisor* in Matlab there are no checks available.

A restart of Matlab sometimes fixes this, however it is really inconsistent, and I've had to reinstall Matlab several times due to this and it is really annoying since I have scripts that depends on the Model Advisor. If I would to run the empty Model Advisor programatically it of course results in **'Systems not run: 1 of 1'**

Here is an image of the empty Model Advisor.
[Empty Model Advisor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGOVE.png)
I am using the following version of Matlab

```
MATLAB Version: 9.2.0.538062 (R2017a)
```

I have tried reinstalling Matlab several times, I have also tried refreshing the Model Advisor cache with the following command without any luck.

```
Advisor.Manager.refresh_customizations()
```

Any thoughts on this? 
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There was a conflict in the *sl_customization* that hid the checks.

Comment: Perhaps you could improve upon this answer to help others. How did you identify the conflict and how did you resolve it?